# Exporting Sharepoint files to SQL

Tags: sql, database, sharepoint, export

I'm fairly new to Microsoft SharePoint and I just want to ask if it is possible to export the files uploaded in share point to .sequel format?

I'm currently trying out SharePoint Online but can't find any solutions for this one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this. You could use the SharePoint Object Model to access the files and then write them into SQL using CSharp.

There is a good blog post by Terry Marshall entitles [SharePoint 2010 - Exporting Lists To SQL Server](http://www.terrymarshall.com.au/Blog/tabid/162/EntryId/164/SharePoint-2010-Exporting-Lists-to-SQL-Server-Part-1.aspx)

It relates to SharePoint 2010 but it would be possible to take those approaches to export the files to SQL from SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint online.

Alternatively there are some third part tools that can do this. [AxioWorks SQList can continuously export SharePoint data and files to a normalised SQL database](http://www.axioworks.com/sqlist) if it's something you are looking to do on an ongoing basis.